# how to fetch a data from one file location and to run using tcl code

Tags: testing, tcl, automated-tests

In tcl how to get the data from one file location and to run that data using TCL code .
for example 
In the folder 1 there is config file ,i want to get the informations of config file and i want to execute the information that is present or not,

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration file contains Tcl code, it's just:

```
# Put the filename in quotes if you want, or in a variable, or ...
source /the/path/to/the/file.tcl
```

If the file contains Tcl code but you don't trust it, you can use a “safe interpreter” context. This disables many commands, giving a much more restricted set of capabilities that you can then add specific exceptions to (with `interp alias`):

```
# Make the context
set i [interp create -safe]

# Set up a way for the context to let the master find out about what to
# really set
interp alias $i configure {} recordConfiguration
proc recordConfiguration args {
    puts "configured with $args"
}

# Evaluate the script (note that [source] is hidden by default) in the context
$i invokehidden source /the/path/to/the/file.tcl

# Dispose the context
interp delete $i
```

If the file *isn't* Tcl code, you have to parse it. That's a substantially more complex matter, so much so that we'll need to know the format of the file before we can answer.

Comment: can u tell me with another simple example how to get a data from config directory using tcl code

Comment: @vinu, what kind of data? what does it look like? is the data actually Tcl code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read data (like text strings) from a file then you'll have to open a channel for that particular file like this:

```
set fileid [open "path/to/your/file.txt" r]
```

Read [open manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm).

Then you can use [gets command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/gets.htm) to read data from the file through the channel `fileid` .